# what is the difference between command running in shell and in program?

Tags: shell, alsa

I want to test if aplay can playback wave files continuously so first try 2 different commands in shell window (putty to the target):

```
aplay -P -c 1 -t raw -r 16000 -f S16_LE audio/test1.raw

aplay -P -c 1 -t wav -r 32000 -f S16_LE audio/test2.wav
```

both are working.

Now I created a simple program main() to auto run with C++:

```
    char ac[100] = {0};
    int n = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("---%d \n", ++n);
        strcpy(ac, "sudo nice -n -10 aplay -P -c 1 -t raw -r 16000 -f S16_LE audio/test1.raw");
        system(ac);

        delay(1000); //delay 1s

        strcpy(ac, "sudo nice -n -10 aplay -P -c 1 -t wav -r 32000 -f S16_LE audio/test2.wav");
        system(ac);
        delay(1000);
    }
```

The delay() function:

```
int delay(int nMs)
{
    struct timespec requested_time, remaining;
    requested_time.tv_nsec = (nMs%1000)*1000000;
    requested_time.tv_sec = (nMs/1000);
    return nanosleep (&requested_time, &remaining);
}
```

The result is aplay stuck at the test2.wav:

```
root@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/TEST# sudo nice -n -10 aplay -P -c 1 -t raw -r 16000 -f S16_LE audio/test1.raw
Playing raw data 'audio/test1.raw' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono  --- ok, heard 
root@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/TEST# sudo nice -n -10 aplay -P -c 1 -t wav -r 32000 -f S16_LE audio/test2.wav
Playing WAVE 'audio/test2.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 32000 Hz, Mono   --- ok, heard 

root@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/TEST# ./Test
--- 1
Playing raw data 'audio/test1.raw' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
Playing WAVE 'audio/test2.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 32000 Hz, Mono --- ok, heard
^CAborted by signal Interrupt...
--- 2
Playing raw data 'audio/test1.raw' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono --- nok, no sound, hang
^CAborted by signal Interrupt...
Playing WAVE 'audio/test2.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 32000 Hz, Mono  --- nok, no sound, hang
^CAborted by signal Interrupt...
--- 3
Playing raw data 'audio/test1.raw' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono --- nok, no sound, hang
^CAborted by signal Interrupt...
^C
```

This is out of my knowledge... Can anyone help explain and how to prevent that? The OS I used is:

```
lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linaro
Description:    Linaro 11.10 (development branch)
Release:        11.10
Codename:       oneiric

cat /proc/version:
Linux version 3.0.35-2666-gbdde708 (root@jt-G31M-S2L) (gcc version 4.6.2 20110630 (prerelease) (Freescale MAD -- Linaro 2011.07 -- Built at 2011/08/10 09:20) ) #14 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 26 11:21:54 CST 2016
```

The sound card is wm8962-audio.

Comment: Did it play `test2.wav` then stop?

Comment: No, no audio output for test2.wav, only see the print info on screen, and stuck there. and then the following test1.raw also stuck without audio. To back to normal, need to reboot the system.

Comment: Get rid of the `sudo`. And of the `strcpy()`, though that's not what's causing your problems.

Comment: removed both sudo and strcpy, the result is same. however, when change delay time from 1s to 5s, the playback is normal for every cycle. So the problem is on "aplay" itself? Why aplay need so long time to clean up?